# Adding poi-ooxml dependency to Maven JavaFx project gives me this error - Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

I would like to write to xlsx file using apache poi and poi-ooxml. I created a new maven command line project, added the dependencies and it works fine.
However, if I create a new JavaFX Maven project and add the poi and poi-ooxml dependencies, I get the following error.

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\R\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xalan-2.7.2.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module.

This is my pom.xml file :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ridoo</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenFXTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.ridoo.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my module-info.java file

```
module com.ridoo {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires org.apache.poi.ooxml;
requires org.apache.poi.poi;

opens com.ridoo to javafx.fxml;
exports com.ridoo;
```

}

How do I fix this?

Comment: This error is based on the [Batik dependencies](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65103). For the upcoming 5.0.1 I've changed them to optional. You can fix the issue locally, similar to our [poi-ooxml build](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/poi-ooxml/build.gradle?view=markup) - see fixBatik task. Feel welcomed to comment on [Batiks bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/BATIK-1260) ... but with quite a few Apache projects, there are only a hand full (or less) committers active anymore

Comment: @kiwiwings Thank you for the reply. Is there anyway you can point me in the direction of some documentation with a step by step on how to go about fixing this locally? I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: You simply need to download the batik-script jar and modify the META-INF/services/org.apache.batik.script.InterpreterFactory file. The line with "...RhinoInterpreterFactory" needs to be commented out. Then you need to make sure, that your module-path contains the modified and not the downloaded batik-script. So copy all dependencies excluding batik-script to a new directory and copy your modified batik-script there - the module-path is then this new directory

Comment: @kiwiwings Okay so this is what I've done. Downloaded batik-script.jar and modified it using vim. The line with "...RhinoInterpreterFactory" is now commented out. I went into my local Maven repository and replaced the batik-script.jar with the modified one. In intellij, browsing to the META-INF/services/org.apache.batik.script.InterpreterFactory file I can confirm that the line is commented out. I get the same error.

Comment: I tried excluding "xalan" in my pom.xml and I now get the following : java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules batik.all and batik.transcoder export package org.apache.batik.transcoder.svg2svg to module batik.rasterizer.ext

Comment: batiks maven dependencies are also messed up. batik-all also contains that InterpreterFactory file AND maven references all submodules. So either use only batik-all without its batik-* dependencies and modify it OR exclude batik-all and only use its submodules and the modified batik-script jar

Comment: @kiwiwings This worked. Thanking you kindly for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who needs to get poi-ooxml up and running, this is my solution.

Maven downloads batik and other dependencies such ad xalan that are not necessary for this to work. Therefore, do not use Maven for this except for a couple of dependencies which I will mention.

1. Download and extract the official poi binary zip from [poi.apache.org](https://poi.apache.org/download.html)
2. From the downloaded and extracted zip, navigate to the auxiliary folder and modify the META-INF/services/org.apache.batik.script.InterpreterFactory file in the batik-all-1.13.jar using vim or vi. Comment out the line "org.apache.batik.bridge.RhinoInterpreterFactory" and save.
3. Add all jar files as an external library from the following directories:
   -auxilliary, lib and ooxml-lib. Add all jars from the poi-5.0.0 directory except for **poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar**.
4. From maven, add the following dependencies and you are good to go :

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
   ```